# How should I preferably "run" Python scripts in RStudio? Through run (using reticulate::repl_python()?) or source?

Tags: python, r, rstudio

I just started to use RStudio with Python (up to now everything works) and I wonder if there is a preferred way to run scripts such as my small `Test.py` containing

```
import inspect
import os

a = 5
print(a)

print(inspect.currentframe())
os.chdir("C:/.../") # a path, whatever you like
cwd = os.getcwd()
 
# print the current directory
print("Current working directory is:", cwd)
```

There is an answer for R [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23923638/5784831) but this does not consider Python. I tried the flollowing:

1. Source (Ctrl + Shift + S) from R-console => R-console is used

[image]

2. Start Python console using `reticulate::repl_python()` in R-console => Change from R- to Python-console

[image]

3. Source (Ctrl + Shift + S) from Python-console => Change from Python- to R-console

[image]

It seems, `reticulate::repl_python()` forces the `quit` first.

4. Run lines or a selection using "run" (Ctrl + Enter) => Starts Python-console and stays there

[image]

---

**This [reference for reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) and its description did not help**: The reticulate package provides a comprehensive set of tools for interoperability between Python and R... Reticulate embeds a Python session within your R session, enabling seamless, high-performance interoperability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Too long for a comment. Maybe it helps others and hopefully, everything is correct)

What I understand now, RStudio provides an editor for R (not surprising).
When you run Python code within RStudio, there is an R-wrapper for Python translating the code to R.

Thus, RStudio does not switch the editor to a native Python-IDE (which was my expectation) like VScode or others.

What I understand now: If you have projects with Python only, use a Python editor.

Answer (score 3):

In the RStudio IDE there should be a "Source script" button (keyboard shortcut on a Mac: shift-cmd-S) which sources the script.

[image]

From the terminal this is then how it looks:

```
reticulate::source_python('~/Untitled.py')
```

Comment: So the idea is to always work within the R environment? The Python console is in most cases unused? What happens in case of debugging, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44728031/5784831)? (I could not make debugging work using ipdb. If I execute line by line, it still throws an error `IndexError: list index out of range` when source it also throws an error stating `Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : IndexError: list index out of range`)

Comment: Hi @Christoph, I am not very familiar with more advanced uses (like debugging) of the RStudio IDE for Python. I am not sure why you have decided for RStudio - are you working with both R and Python? I love the functionality when it comes to R, but for Python projects I very much prefer VScode, where I also think debugging is really excellent.